# Is there a shorthand to typecast value in java8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Currently I am doing it like:

```
.map((service) -> (ClassType) service.getList())
```

Is there a shorthand for this

```
.map((ClassType) Service::getList)
```

Comment: No. But the type-cast has the smell of a design problem. Why do you need to cast in the first place?

Comment: @JBNizet The Service class is third party lib. Which returns a List of object instead of a specific class.

Comment: The closest I can think of is `.map(Service::getList).map(ClassType.class::cast)` but I find it less readable than using the lambda expression.

Comment: @VivekGoel, consider creating a wrapper class or bunch of utility methods which call that third-party API performing all the necessary casts, then use that methods. This way you will not have ugly casts in business logic code.

Comment: @Vivek Goel: there is nothing wrong with the Service class returning the list. The question is why you can’t simply use that list but need that specific class. *That’s* the design smell. If the API designers of the Service class decided to declare `List` as a return type they usually intent you to *not* rely on the list to be of a specific type.

Comment: @VivekGoel What's the next method in your function chain after map? The problem is more likely to be your consumer than the supplier.

Comment: @SteveK Service::getList should return a object of images. Next function call in this chain is Image::getURL

Comment: @VivekGoel How do you pass a List into Image::getURL?

Comment: @SteveK Currently I was planning to do so. 
.map((Image) Service::getList).flatMap(Image::getURL)

Comment: @VivekGoel That's backwards.. you `flatMap(Service::getList)` to get a stream containing all items from all lists, and then `map(Image::getURL)` to get a stream of `URL` items. You can easily make a utility method which takes an Object, casts it to an Image and returns getURL: `public static URL getURL(Object o){ return ((Image)o).getURL()}` and then just call that in your `map()` call: `map(UtilClass::getURL)`